# Downloading image from DropBox using Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to download an image from dropbox to my desktop using Python. The script below runs to completion without issues and creates a JPEG file on the desktop (about 200+ KB in size). But when I try to open it, I get a file damaged / Preview cannot read file error message:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import shutil


url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/rest_of_the_url'
db_username = 'user_name'
db_password = 'password'

downloaded_file = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(db_username, db_password))

dest_file = open('/Users/aj/Desktop/test.jpg', 'w+')

dest_file.write(downloaded_file.content)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: Found the solution. It had to do with the 'dl' parameter in the dropbox link. This parameter needs to be set to 0.

Original link:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3xujisscbp92to/2.jpg?dl=0
```

Need to set the dl parameter to 1:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3xujisscbpj92to/2.jpg?dl=1
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the file as text? What's actually in it?

Comment: No - I did not. But I dug around a little more and figured out the issue. It seems like I need to change the "dl" parameter at the end of the download link. When you copy the link from dropbox, it is originally set to 0. Made an edit to my original post explaining it.

Comment: In the URL below "Need to set the dl parameter to 0:", the `dl` parameter set to 1. Which is it? And if you do have a solution, you should post it as a proper answer.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it to say 1. Will post it as a proper answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. It had to do with the 'dl' parameter in the dropbox link. This parameter needs to be set to 0.

Original link:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3xujisscbp92to/2.jpg?dl=0
```

Need to set the dl parameter to 1:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3xujisscbpj92to/2.jpg?dl=1
```