# dropbox.exceptions.ApiError: ... CreateFileRequestError('validation_error', None)

Tags: python, request, dropbox-api

I want to get and save the URL of an image to a variable via dropbox API in python. I'm following this [guide](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2019/04/streamline-file-collection-with-the-file-request-api/?_tk=guides_lp&_ad=python_tutorial3&_camp=file_request) but I get the error shown in the title.

I searched for the function [dbx.file_requests_create](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.file_requests_create) and probably doing something wrong with title or destination. Should the title be some existing source? Because I just set it by myself.

```
import dropbox

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('Y2_M...aVP')
req = dbx.file_requests_create(title='Images', destination='/C:/Users/Dropbox/Apps/myProject/image.jpg')
print req.url
print req.id
```

**EDIT**: I found this link [FileRequestError](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/T_Dropbox_Api_FileRequests_FileRequestError_ValidationError.htm). It says:

> There was an error validating the request. For example, the title was invalid, or there were disallowed characters in the destination path.

**EDIT-2 [SOLVED]**: Thanks to Aran-Fey and Greg for their comments, I solved the problem by replacing `req = dbx.file_requests_create(title='Images', destination='/C:/Users/Dropbox/Apps/myProject/image.jpg')` with

> `req = dbx.sharing_create_shared_link_with_settings('/image.jpg', settings=None)`

Also, for people who have problem with getting the image when sharing it,  just **change** the last character of the link from **0 to 1** as mentioned on [this](https://help.dropbox.com/desktop-web/force-download) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43440112/downloading-image-from-dropbox-using-python).
You can add this line to the end `newURL = req.url[:-1] + "1"` to solve the matter.

Comment: `/C:/Users` doesn't look like a valid path to me...

Comment: How should the destination of a source be?

Comment: Am I using a wrong function? I set the destination like that since I thought it's the path of stored image in my pc which is connected to dropbox.

Comment: A path like `/C:/Users...` is not a valid Dropbox path. (You appear to have included a local Windows path.) Regardless, based on your description it sounds like `file_requests_create` isn't the functionality you actually want anyway. If you want to make a shared link for an existing image in the account, you should use [`sharing_create_shared_link_with_settings`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.sharing_create_shared_link_with_settings) instead.

Comment: Thank you Aran-Fey and Greg for your suggestions and your fast response as well. @Greg, since you gave the solution to my problem, I think you can post it as an answer so that I will mark it as accepted.